# Present View Controller with navigation bar without Segue

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using google maps SDK. They have a neat feature where you press a `UIButton` to call the following method and a VC is presented from the right hand side to the left hand side just like how you would do with Segue. But the difference is that there was no segue or anything that I need to call myself and the google function does it automatically,  The new VC also comes with navigation bar with back button. I noticed that the navigation bar is different to the one from previous VC and the back button is also different. I want to do the same for one of my current VC and by implementing a function that achieves the same effect (And I do not want to use segue for some reason that would be off topic here). I am thinking how google have done it might be

Possible solution? Present a newVC to with transition type from right to left and Allow that VC to have it's own navigation bar (Or perhaps that might just be a `UIView` with back button (I am not sure). However, that VC needs to be able to be dismissed either by pressing back button or dragging the screen from left edge to right (And is also able to be held half way like the image below). And the dismiss transition type when back button is pressed is from left to right just like normal navigation Bar dismiss Segue.

```
self.placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

[google place sdk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTqeE.jpg)

Comment: Can you not put this google view controller in a navigation controller too? Then you'd be able to use good ol `self.navigationController.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)`

Comment: No, currently I am doing what you said self.navigationController.pushViewController. However, I do not want to do that because doing that will cause a tab bar to be on the bottom of the new "pushed" view controller. I want to have the new VC to be shown over the tabBar. I know I could "hide" the tab bar after the VC is shown but that is ugly. Somehow Google managed to do what I want without associate with my NavVC and TabVC